# How do you get the list of vmInstanceIDs associated with Azure scale sets?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-vm-scale-set

I have looked at the azure cli and tried everything under 'azure vmss' that I could find. I used the armclient and tried different REST request to determine the list. I see several requests in the cli asks for the vmInstanceID for example 'azure vmss restart', 'azure vmss update' and others. My hope is that this will lead to the hostnames of the VMs behind the scale set, or is there another way to get the hostnames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CLI to get the VMSS VM's hostname:

```
C:>azure vmssvm list -g vmss -n vmss
info:    Executing command vmssvm list
data:    ResourceGroupName  Name    ProvisioningState  Location
data:    -----------------  ------  -----------------  --------
data:    VMSS               vmss_0  Succeeded          eastus
info:    vmssvm list command OK
```

Also you can use PowerShell to get the hostname and instance id:

```
PS > Get-AzureRmVmssvm -ResourceGroupName "vmss" -VMScaleSetName "vmss"

ResourceGroupName   Name Location         Sku Capacity InstanceID ProvisioningState
-----------------   ---- --------         --- -------- ---------- -----------------
VMSS              vmss_0   eastus Standard_A1                   0         Succeeded
VMSS              vmss_2   eastus Standard_A1                   2          Deleting
```

Answer (score 0):

```
instance_id=$(az vmss nic list -g $resource_group --vmss-name $vmss_name --query "[?ipConfigurations[0].privateIpAddress == '$current_ipaddr'].virtualMachine.id" -o tsv | awk -F'/' '{print $11}')
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.